# Determine minor version of library on Linux

Tags: linux, version, shared

How can I know minor version of a library on Linux.

For example on my Linux machine I have libodbc.so.2 and I need to know the exact version of the library, like 2.3.0 or 2.3.2.

Is there some Linux command that I can run on the library to get its version?
I tried ./libodbc.so.2 -v but got Segmentation fault.

Comment: Example, with the `ls -l` command ...... `ls -l /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2` : `/usr/lib64/libodbc.so.2 -> libodbc.so.2.0.0`

Comment: Running "ls -l ./libodbc.so.2" just lists information about the file, referring to the library as libodbc.so.2 without adding any additional version information

Answer (score 0):

> `ldd` should be the tool of your choice. That gives you the shared library actually linked.

Refer this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163138/how-do-i-find-what-version-of-libc-my-application-links-to).

Comment: using ldd didn't give me additional information. Here is the output portion related to libodbc: libodbc.so.2 => /lib/libodbc.so.2
                      /lib/libodbc.so.2:
As you can see there isn't any information about minor version of the library.